# Number of threads in Loop parallelisation using OpenMP in C

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I am learning OpenMP these days. I have read many blogs on internet and after reading them i have a very common doubt about "number of threads in loop parallelization". take the example below

```
int x,y;
#pragma omp parallel for private(y)
for(x=0; x < width; x++)
{
    for(y=0; y < height; y++)
    {
        finalImage[x][y] = RenderPixel(x,y, &sceneData);
    }
}
```

In this example how many threads are being used for parallelization. Is it the standard way or we should explicitly tell about number of threads ?.

Comment: Whether you want to force a certain number of threads to be used or let openmp determine it for you, that depends... You can always query for the number of threads by `omp_get_num_threads()`

Comment: If I want to force certain number of threads to be used then what are the factors that i keep in mind. e.g Suppose my system has processor with two cores then does it limits the number of threads to two ?

Comment: The number of actual cores does not limit the number of threads. On a two core machine, you can have four threads, however you are in no way guaranteed that those threads will be occupying all the cores. Threads are logical entities, so you can end up with four threads that are all run on a single core, turn by turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the number of threads otherwise OPENMP will automatically use what is available.
You can print the number of threads like the following

```
    #pragma omp parallel private(tid)
    {
        tid=omp_get_thread_num();
        if(tid==0){
            nthreads=omp_get_num_threads();
            printf("Number of threads = %d\n",nthreads);
        }
```

In order to run a program with a specific number (2 here) of threads, in bash you can run like the following

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./program
```

Comment: Should I type this `OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./program` in terminal to run program with 2 threads? Can u please tell me this. Also should the code to run two parent and child `for` loop be different in open mp from  normal single threaded application. That I have been searching for some time but no luck. For example if I have i j loop then should i refractor code first before including openmp directive? Can u tell

Comment: Hi @user786, yes you need to type it in a terminal.